# Cannot view project via Enterprise Editor in IBM Rad

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-rad

I think Rad has updated or done something behind the scenes but when I go to open up my project the node that expands says "Security Editor". I cannot edit any file/servlet etc in my project.

When I click on "Security Editor" I get a message stating:
"The Security Editor does not support the use of Security Annotations. All security information must be specified in the deployment descriptor to be displayed and edited with the Security Editor"

I have had a look in application.xml in the EAR file but cannot see what to do?

I am a Websphere newbie and this is my first J2EE project that nearly done. I just don't get whats changed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAD is only warning you that if you define security constraints though the use of annotations, it will not show in the security editor. This prompt can be disabled from the Preferences->Java EE->Security page. You can ignore this and still use the security editor if it is your preferred method of configuring security.

Comment: Cheers! I had to restart the workspace afterwards but its fixed now